# Linux space check

Tags: linux, space

Collectively check space of files in linux...

I have nearly more than 100  of files ...to check the size collectively...

---

*Edit*: What I need is: I have a folder containing 1000 files and I need something so that I can calculate the total sum [*of what?*] of 100 files only which I need...not all 1000 files.....

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Do you need the sum of the number of bytes in those files?  Or the number of disk blocks used by those files?  Presumably, you have a way of determining the list of 100 files that you are interested in.  Depending on your answers to these questions, you will get better or worse input.

Comment: sum can be checked by ls -ltrh | wc -l

now i want to check the size of this 100 files i selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit vague ... Assuming all you want is to get the total size of a bunch of files, there's any number of solutions.

If the files are all in the same directory, one very easy way is to just use

```
ls -lh | head -1
```

This prints a single line showing the "total" number, with a friendly "human-readable" (that's the `-h` option to ls) unit even.

Note that this does not work with wildcards, since then ls suppresses its "total"-line.

Answer (score 3):

This command will give you the size in kilobytes of all the individual files/directories in the current directory:

```
du -ks *
```

This command will give you the combined total size of the current directory:

```
du -ks .
```

If you need to recurse and get more detailed info, the find command might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total size of all files in the current directory (In "human readable format")

```
du -sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no linux guru, but there should be some switch of the `ls` command that shows size.

If that fails, look into using `du`.

Answer (score 0):

Using gdu:

```
aaa:vim70> gdu 
5028    ./doc
4420    ./syntax
.
.
.
176     ./compiler
16      ./macros/hanoi
16      ./macros/life
48      ./macros/maze
20      ./macros/urm
200     ./macros
252     ./keymap
18000   .
```

You can use **`--max-depth`** to limit the depth of the search:

```
aaa:vim70> gdu --max-depth=1
5028    ./doc
136     ./print
76      ./colors
4420    ./syntax
420     ./indent
628     ./ftplugin
1260    ./autoload
64      ./plugin
800     ./tutor
3348    ./spell
176     ./compiler
200     ./macros
112     ./tools
844     ./lang
252     ./keymap
18000   .
```

Notice that the subdirectories of  `macros` don't appear.

or even:

```
aaa:vim70> gdu --max-depth=0
18000   .
```

The default unit is kilobytes.  You can use `-h` to get it in human readable form:

```
aaa:vim70> gdu --max-depth=1 -h
5.0M    ./doc
136k    ./print
76k     ./colors
4.4M    ./syntax
420k    ./indent
628k    ./ftplugin
1.3M    ./autoload
64k     ./plugin
800k    ./tutor
3.3M    ./spell
176k    ./compiler
200k    ./macros
112k    ./tools
844k    ./lang
252k    ./keymap
18M     .
```

Comment: @vivek: these two comments are not very sensible - though the first is better than the second.